# Connecting MySQL to Excel for Mac -- "Specified driver could not be loaded"

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, mysql

I have installed the MySQL to Mac OBDC connector that can be found at [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/), and followed the instructions that you can find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html). But when I go to actually try to pull data into Excel, I get the failure/error described in the title.  Specifically, I have entered the following information into the configuration panel under "System DSN":
server: [IP address]
user: [username]
password: [my password]
database: [name_of_database].

I have tried both the ANSI and the Unicode versions of the driver and get the same result.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does the error message starting with "IM002" or "IM003"? There is a official article mentioning the similar error:[About iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/FAQ#%5BiODBC%5D%20%5BDriver%20Manager%5DSpecified%20driver%20could%20not%20be%20loaded). Maybe you get help from the thread on the similar issue: [macOS Connector/MySQL ODBC driver could not be loaded in Excel for Mac 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896893/macos-connector-mysql-odbc-driver-could-not-be-loaded-in-excel-for-mac-2016).

Comment: @HerbGu - yes, it's preceded by IM003.  I will check on the resources you've linked and let you know how it goes.